# How to implement ZenPolicy rules?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Does anyone here know anything about ZenPolicy and how to implement a rule? I am trying to replicate the Do Not Disturb setting where calls are not allowed through, but exceptions are possible, eg. Media sounds, Touch sounds etc. I have managed to disallow calls but when I toggle the exceptions settings (from my app), this reverts to "starred contacts only".
I am attaching a screenshot of what I am trying to replicate in my app. Here is the code I am using so far:

```
3 -> {
                                notificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(
                                    NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY
                                )
                                notificationManager.setNotificationPolicy(
                                    NotificationManager.Policy(
                                        PEOPLE_TYPE_NONE,
                                        PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY,
                                        PRIORITY_SENDERS_ANY
                                    )
                                )
                            }
```

I have also looked through: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/service/notification/ZenModeConfig.java;drc=master;l=754 and https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/service/notification/ZenPolicy.java

and came up with this function, but it doesn't do anything...:

```
fun zenPolicyBuilder(): ZenPolicy.Builder {

    val builder = ZenPolicy.Builder()

    val calls = PRIORITY_CATEGORY_CALLS
    val repeatCallers = PRIORITY_CATEGORY_REPEAT_CALLERS
    val alarms = PRIORITY_CATEGORY_ALARMS
    val media = PRIORITY_CATEGORY_MEDIA
    val system = PRIORITY_CATEGORY_SYSTEM
    val events = PRIORITY_CATEGORY_EVENTS
    val reminders = PRIORITY_CATEGORY_REMINDERS

    return when {
        calls != ZenPolicy.PEOPLE_TYPE_UNSET -> {
            builder.allowCalls(PEOPLE_TYPE_NONE)
        }
        repeatCallers != ZenPolicy.STATE_UNSET -> {
            builder.allowRepeatCallers(repeatCallers == ZenPolicy.STATE_ALLOW)
        }
        alarms != ZenPolicy.STATE_UNSET -> {
            builder.allowAlarms(alarms == ZenPolicy.STATE_ALLOW)
        }
        media != ZenPolicy.STATE_UNSET -> {
            builder.allowMedia(media == ZenPolicy.STATE_ALLOW)
        }
        system != ZenPolicy.STATE_UNSET -> {
            builder.allowSystem(system == ZenPolicy.STATE_ALLOW)
        }
        events != ZenPolicy.STATE_UNSET -> {
            builder.allowEvents(events == ZenPolicy.STATE_ALLOW)
        }
        reminders != ZenPolicy.STATE_UNSET -> {
            builder.allowReminders(reminders == ZenPolicy.STATE_ALLOW)
        }
        else -> builder
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might be interested in future, the first code snippet that I posted actually works fine. The problem was coming from another part of my code which was interfering with this.